# asp.net mvc passing parameters to controller from Jquery ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am making a call to a controller from jquery and I am trying to give it parmeters to it. I am having no luck. It works fine without parmeters when the url is just `/SurveySection/EditLocalization` shouldn't it look like this `/SurveySection/EditLocalization?surveySectionId=3?localizationId=dfasdfas`

jquery

```
   LinkAjax.ajaxRequest("/SurveySection/EditLocalization" += "?surveySectionId=" + "3" + "?languageId=" + $localizationList.val(),
                            "random data",
                            "localizationPartial",
                            null,
                            null,
                            localizationSelectList.renderLocalizationPartialView);
```

This is what my controller looks like

```
        public PartialViewResult EditLocalization(int surveySectionId, string languageId)
        {
        ... ajax call fails because I can't pass in parameters correctly
        }
```

Comment: What is `LinkAjax.ajaxRequest()`?

Comment: @Stephen It's a secret!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the url to the controller is wrong. After the base url, the query string parameters are divided by `?` and the parameters are divided by `&`. Try this:

```
LinkAjax.ajaxRequest("/SurveySection/EditLocalization" += "?surveySectionId=" + "3" + "&languageId=" + $localizationList.val(),
                            "random data",
                            "localizationPartial",
                            null,
                            null,
                            localizationSelectList.renderLocalizationPartialView);
```

Comment: I should have replaced it with the & symbol, silly mistake. Thanks. You posted it before me lol.

Comment: Have to wait 12 minutes before I can check it.